# How to use link the same function to different element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a fresh man to JavaScript. Now I am trying to change the css property for different images. What I want to do is quite simple, just change the transparency of those picture when someone clicked it.

I have the code in my html file like this:

```
<body>
    <img id="aa" src="1.png" onclick="functionaa()">
    <img id="ab" src="3.png" onclick="functionab()">
    <img id="ac" src="2.png" onclick="functionac()">
    <img id="ad" src="4.png" onclick="functionad()">
</body>
```

While, I can do the same function to every image like follow

```
function functionaa()
{
    document.getElementById('aa').style.cssText = 'opacity:0.5';
}

function functionab()
{
    document.getElementById('ab').style.cssText = 'opacity:0.5';
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a way easier for it?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function opacity(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.cssText = 
 'opacity:0.5';
}
```

```html
    <img id="aa" src="facebook-icon.png" onclick="opacity('aa')">
    <img id="ab" src="facebook-icon.png" onclick="opacity('ab')">
    <img id="ac" src="facebook-icon.png" onclick="opacity('ac')">
    <img id="ad" src="facebook-icon.png" onclick="opacity('ad')">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use common function and pass `this` context to function for getting clicked dom object as parameter. This way even you can avoid `getElementById()` method.

```js
function functiona(ele) {
  ele.style.cssText = 'opacity:0.5';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="aa" src="1.png" onclick="functiona(this)">
  <img id="ab" src="3.png" onclick="functiona(this)">
  <img id="ac" src="2.png" onclick="functiona(this)">
  <img id="ad" src="4.png" onclick="functiona(this)">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery and simplify this down to this:
html:

```
<img src="1.png" class="js-dim" />
<img src="3.png" class="js-dim" />
<img src="2.png" class="js-dim" />
<img src="4.png" class="js-dim" />
```

and js:

```
$('.js-dim').click( function(){
    $( this ).fadeOut();
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/k8qpda9t/